# How do i make fullcalendar get all events in one call from my mvc json feed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, fullcalendar

Two parts to this question first, using the simple example how do i get fullcalendar to get all the events from my JSON feed without needing to paginate back and forth?  My calendars are short term and very specific so don't need to reload the events when scrolling through the dates.  Here's the Action Method:

```
public JsonResult CalendarData(int id)
{
    List<object> json = new List<object>();

    json.Add(
        new
        {
            title = "Click for Google",
            start = string.Format("/Date({0})/", DateTime.Now.ToUnixTime()),
            end = string.Format("/Date({0})/", DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToUnixTime()),
            url = "http://google.com/"
        });

    return this.Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here's the JS i'm using to try get all the events back in one call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: false,
        events: "{controller}/calendardata/1",
        loading: function (bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loading').show();
            else $('#loading').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

And the second part to my questions is what date format should i be returning (not sure if what i have currently is correct?

Thanks

Comment: Date format can be unix time, so it you are doing it right. what's wrong with the code you've written? 'events' is an array of events so afaik it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but I would suspect you could use jQuery getJSON to get the data and then use the fullcalendar events and/or eventsources property to set the events.  That would look something like this:

```
$.getJSON($("#calendarUri").val(), function(data) {
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar(
        {
            events: data
        }
    )
});
```

I believe when you set the events this way, it *should* keep using the same event data as you page through months, weeks, etc.

Then in your view:

```
@Hidden("calendarUri", Url.Action("CalendarData", new { id = 1 }))
```

Note that by using a hidden field in your view to store the URL of your event feed you won't run into trouble if you change your routing.

Answer (score 0):

This article is very useful for me of full calendar json value show in events.

```
@Html.Hidden("calendarUri", Url.Action("LoadCalendarData","Home"))

jq.getJSON($("#calendarUri").val(), function (data) {
    jq('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            //left: 'prev,next today',
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'title',
            //right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            right: 'next',
            height: '650',
        },
        defaultDate: '@currentDate',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: data
    });
```

});